# Insert blank spaces beetween jpg numbers

Tags: php, css, wordpress, post

With the next code i can change numbers with images (i dont want google know this telephone numbers). It's possible insert blank spaces each 3 numbers/images?

For example, the phone is 111222333 and i want show 111 222 333 in front.

```
<?php global $wp_query; 
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID; 
$i=intval(get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_2', true));
$s='';
while($i>0)
    {
    $digit=$i % 10;
    $i=(int)($i/10);
    $s="<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='http://localhost/buscatuescort/wp-content/themes/Avada/images/$digit.png' width='12' height='18' />$s";
    }
echo $s ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add some kind of **counter** and add a space to the string every 3 iteration steps of the loop. Maybe something like this:

```
$spacer=0;
while($i>0)
    {
    $digit=$i % 10;
    $i=(int)($i/10);
    $s="<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='http://localhost/buscatuescort/wp-content/themes/Avada/images/$digit.png' width='12' height='18' />"
       . ($spacer++ % 3 == 0 ? "&nbsp;" : "") . $s;
    }
```

---

#### Note:

as you are iterating from the last digit backward a number like this:

```
11122233
```

will get printed out like this:

```
11 122 233
```

but if you want to get something like this:

```
111 222 33
```

you will have to write a slightly different loop. Maybe something along these lines:

```
$i = "$i";
$length = strlen($i);
for($key = 0; $key < $length; $key++){
    $s .= ($key % 3 == 0 ? "&nbsp;" : "")
          . "<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='http://localhost/buscatuescort/wp-content/themes/Avada/images/$i[$key].png' width='12' height='18' />";
}
```

*(I changed `$i` into a string to loop through the digits like so `$i[$key]`)*

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is decide a pattern and add spaces accordingly.

For example

```
$newdigit = substr($digit , 0, 3) . " " . substr($digit , 4);
$s="<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='http://localhost/buscatuescort/wp-content/themes/Avada/images/$newdigit.png' width='12' height='18' />$s";
```

I hope it works

Comment: I use this code but don't work. Don't show nothing
<?php global $wp_query; 
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID; 
$i=intval(get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_2', true));
$s='';
while($i>0)
    {
    $digit=$i % 10;
    $i=(int)($i/10);
 $newdigit = substr($digit , 0, 3) . " " . substr($digit , 4);
    $s="<img style='vertical-align:middle;' src='http://localhost/buscatuescort/wp-content/themes/Avada/images/$newdigit.png' width='12' height='18' />$s";
    }
echo $s ?>